# Invalid output produced using JSON serialization

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, json, serialization

I'm trying to convert a .NET object into a JSON string, because I want to be able to read the content of this object in the client side.

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IRightsManager rightsInfo = new RightsManager();

    string userId = "ynz362897";

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rightsInfo.GetSectorsForUser(userId));

    Session["test"] = json;

    return View();
}
```

GetSectorsForUser returns an object which have only one attributes, a list of of another object. Here is the model:

```
public class Sector
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Sector(string code, string name)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class RightsList
{
    public IList<Sector> Sectors;

    public RightsList(IList<Sector> sectors)
    {
        this.Sectors = sectors;
    }
}
```

Here is GetSectorsForUser code:

```
public RightsList GetSectorsForUser(string userId)
{
    IRightsManagerDB rightsManager = new RightsManagerDB();

    RightsList rightsList = new RightsList(rightsManager.GetSectorsForUser(userId));

    return(rightsList);
}
```

The result currently produced by my code is:

```
"{\"Sectors\":[{\"Code\":\"01\",\"Name\":\"FME\"},{\"Code\":\"02\",\"Name\":\"DML\"}]}"
```

Which is unreadable with a for in jQuery client side. I am stuck on this for hours, and I cant find any solutions.

Here is the client code:

```
var sectors =  @Session["Sectors"];

$.each(sectors, function (i, item) {
    $('#comboSector').append($('<option>', {
        text: item.Name,
        value : item.Code
    }));
});
```

Comment: What does the client code that reads the output look like?

Comment: at first glance, that seems like perfectly fine JSON...

Comment: code is crashing at : var sectors =  @Session["Sectors"]; I'm trying to put the output in sectors and then go throught with a for. EDIT

Comment: Is that client code a .js file, or part of a .cshtml? If it's a .js file, then the `@Session["Sectors"];` bit won't work without Razor.

Comment: It's part of a .cshtml

Comment: **Your problem needs to go in the title of your post.**  Users coming from Google trying to figure out how to "Serialize a Net object into a JSON string" will only discover a troubleshooting problem, and you will have wasted their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MainMa Thanks for your answer. Like you said, it was not very clear technically for me. I did a bit of research and clean up my code according to standards. Now that I have a better understanding of Ajax, here is how I fixed my problem.

This is my ajax request client side.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetSectors',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (idx, sector) {
                $('#comboSector').append($('<option>', {
                    text: sector.Name,
                    value: sector.Code
                }));
            })
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });

})
```

Which is answered by my controller server side:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSectors()
{
    Sector[] sectors = sectorManager.GetSectorsForUser("cn873284").ToArray();
    return Json(sectors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now my combo is initialized with parameter sent by the server. No more use of Session.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're sending the object through AJAX...

ASP.NET MVC handles JSON serialization for you. This means that you don't need the:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rightsInfo.GetSectorsForUser(userId));
```

line. What happens is that you serialize the object yourself, and then ASP.NET MVC serializes it one more time, leading to the actual result, that is a string serialized as JSON. In other words:

- The first serialization leads to `{"Sectors": ...`,
- The serialization of the previous string leads to `"{\"Sectors\": ...`.

### If you're embedding the object in JavaScript within HTML...

It seems like this is what you are actually doing, and:

```
var sectors =  @Session["Sectors"];
```

is a Razor file. This is a very weird approach (mixing languages, dynamically generating JavaScript, accessing the session from your view¹), but, well, let's assume you know what you are doing.

What happens here is that `sectors` variable points to a string which contains the JSON-serialized object, not the object itself. If you need to get the object, do:

```
var sectorsObj = JSON.parse(sectors);
$.each(sectorsObj, ...
```

`JSON.parse` decodes a JSON-serialized object. Similarly, `JSON.stringify` converts an object to its JSON representation.

---

<sup>¹ Accessing the session from your view like you do is not only an abuse of the MVC model and refactoring-unfriendly, but also [technically wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878287/240613). Limit the view to the contents of the model, and eventually the view bag, when relevant. Avoid using global variables, session, request/response object, etc.</sup>

Comment: So I can just add the object in Session like: Session["test"] = rightsInfo.GetSectorsForUser("ynz362897")? And read it in javascript without problem?

Comment: Because doing so and trying to read it like i did in my edit above, I get the following message: "GED is undefined", as my js is reading that var sectors =  GED.Models.RightsList

Comment: @Quentin: I'm sorry, I haven't read your question carefully enough before answering. Look at the second part of the edited answer, this should give you enough clues.

Comment: @MainMa: Consider leaving feedback on [New Site Name and Scope Proposals](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/new-site-name-and-scope-proposals?cb=1).  If questions like this need to be in scope, we need to know that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: notice that I was among the persons who voted to migrate the question to StackOverflow. This being said, the fact that the question is off-topic on a site shouldn't prevent a user from answering the question even before it is migrated to the appropriate SE site.

Comment: @MainMa: I wouldn't do that.  It makes no sense to answer an off-topic question, on the off-chance that it might actually get migrated to the correct one.  Most off-topic questions on Programmers get closed, not migrated.

Comment: @Quentin why are you even using JSON here?  why not make this list part of a viewmodel and pass it to the view?  And if you need this as a separate ajax call, you shold change the return type to a Json instead of returning a view.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: interesting point. How about [discussing it on Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8069/6605)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry for posting in the wrong place. I will no make the same mistake next time!